# View vs Table in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, sql-server-2008, sql-view

**TASK:** for the dashboard purpose, I have a complex select query with lot of joins and sub queries which get the data from multiple tables.

**OPTION 1:** I can create a view with that `SELECT` query and Spotfire can use that view as the data source for its dashboard.

**OPTION 2:** I can create a SSIS package by using that `SELECT` query as a source and I can load the data into a single table *ONCE PER DAY*. Spotfire can use that single table as a source for its dashboard.

**NOTE:** I don't want it REAL TIME. Dashboard can update every night (once per day).

**My understanding:** I know that the view is basically a stored `SELECT` query. If I create a view, every time when a user accesses the Dashboard, it will try to access the view. That means, in the back end view will hit the underlying tables in the database. Instead of this, I can simply have specific table loaded once per a day by SSIS. SO that Dash will touch this table instead of the actual highly transactional tables.

Can you suggest me with an option along with explanation?

Comment: Sounds like either one would work. You are going to have to make this decision based on your requirements.

Comment: You could try to use `WITH ENCRYPTION` or `WITH SCHEMABINDING` when creating the view to get rid of your concern, and creating a SSIS package just for populating data to one table is kinda over engineered, I would give 1 vote to using views xD

Comment: As Sean Lange said, it really depends on your requirements. If you've got space constraints and want to avoid physicalization, a view is better. If it's a complex or resource intensive query it might be prohibitively costly to have it run every time someone needs that data. There are many considerations that depends on your use case.

Comment: @LONG not sure what with encryption has to do with this issue. And of course that is no way to protect sql code anyway. It is trivial to remove it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To some extent, this is a matter of opinion.  But, you have defined the following situation:

- Dashboard is only updated once per day, so it should be constant during the day.
- Underlying tables are being used for transactional purposes.
- Required query is at least somewhat complex.

Combined, these strongly argue for creating a dashboard table in the middle of the night, to simplify the querying.

In many environments, the underlying transactional tables are not used directly for reporting.  Instead the tables are copied to a reporting environment (either periodically or in realish-time) and the reporting environment is used for reporting.

Comment: Thanks for your response Gordon, I am thinking creating the separate table for that exact same reason.

Answer (score 5):

You seem to have covered most of the issues.

The advantage to the View is that it's real-time, as of the moment the report is run. The disadvantage is that it's live load on your system, including not only CPU, RAM, and disk I/O but also (often more importantly) table and row locks.

The advantage for the SSIS package is disconnecting your reporting load from your production load (again: especially the reduced locking contention is a win here), and being able to create special reporting-only indexes to make your reports run faster without necessarily needing to maintain these indexes as changes come in for live tables (especially since the indexes useful for reporting are often very different than the indexes useful for production updates). The disadvantages are increased complexity and failure points (what if the SSIS package starts failing?), stale data, and the fact that if you're just moving to a special table on the same server the reports still use some CPU, disk, and RAM resources from your production server, even if it is reduced.

Personally, I tend to prefer using Views, right up until the point where I don't :) .

By this I mean once I start using SSIS packages to move data to a separate location for reports, I want to go "all-in" on that process. Don't just do one report or table on the same server; get a separate reporting server (or even a full-fledged data warehouse solution) and move as much as possible over to it. Then make sure someone is responsible for monitoring it's health and the health of the migration packages. I'll also start working to change the corporate culture so everyone is comfortable seeing yesterday's data. But I want to put this off for as long as I can, and stick with Views until I start seeing a tangible reason to move to some kind of real data warehouse or analytics product that will justify this cost.

Comment: Thanks for your patient response Joel. However If we Create separate table for reporting, it wont effect the CPU /Ram as View effects. Bcz, in case of table, complex query will run only once per day. But in case View, that complex query need to run every time user access the dashboard.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly I agree with the comments and answers around it depends on your requirements. In my experience, the VIEW option is always initially appealing as it is simple to implement and maintain as there are less moving parts.

However, as data volumes increase, the performance of the dashboard and the negative performance impact to the underlying transactional system eventually resulted in refactoring the implementation.

In our scenario, separating the concerns of reporting from the transactional system was correct thing to do. Implementing Materialized Views (think of data snapshots) for our reporting, removed the locking, timeouts and server overloading which had plagued users and given the system a bad reputation.

If you have the time upfront and believe the your data volumes may grow significantly, seriously give materialized views due consideration.